# How to update local branch with changes from remote git branch without having to 'merge' commit

Tags: git, github

I have a remote branch where I have pushed some changes from **PC A** (I am the only one working on this branch). I also have **PC B** where the same branch is cloned (is tracking the same remote branch as from **PC A**), but it is missing the latest changes that I just pushed to the branch from **PC A**. When I run `git pull` on **PC B** to get the latest changes, git obviously complains about 'merge conflicts'. Since I am tracking the same remote branch from **PC A** and from **PC B**, I *do not* want to make a merge commit every time and I also do not want to rebase. I just want the branch on **PC B** to get updated to the exact state as the remote branch without having to make any commits whatsoever. How can this be achieved in git?

Comment: I don't understand your 'obviously'. In my understanding, B has no change that A would not have. So except if you have a policy of always merge, it should only be a (hard) reset to the remote tip.

Comment: Remove the branch, pull, and checkout again. Alternatively don't pull, instead fetch and manually reset the head to the remote branch

Comment: @LaurentG Since he has this issue, I'm assuming he is amending commits and force pushing.

Comment: @fredrik You are right, I should have told about fetch first, too.

Comment: @fredrik I agree. Either A or B is re-writing commits in order for the conflicts to happen.

Comment: @fredrik the branch is a feature branch which I have to rebase on the develop from time to time, to get the latest changes on develop (I prefer rebase over merge and use the Gitflow workflow in general). After which, I make a force push (without any options, which I will need to change according to the answer I accepted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily reset with:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard @{u}
```

Note `@{u}` is [shorthand for the upstream branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#_tracking_branches), usually `origin/your-branch-name`.

**Note**: since you're sometimes getting conflicts, that means you are re-writing your commits and force pushing. (Maybe with rebase, or amend.) That's a totally fine workflow (I do the same on my own branches), but, when you force push, it's a good habit to use:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

By force pushing that way you're less likely to accidentally blow away a change you made on another computer that you haven't seen yet. If you do that and get an error, then you need to `git fetch` and compare your local and remote branch to see if you need to reset (or pull with rebase) first, before pushing out your latest change.

If you don't always force-push your amends/rebases right away, then you may want to compare local and remote before doing the reset as well, so you don't blow away something locally that you never pushed out.

Comment: Will that syntax work regardless of shell?

Comment: @fredrik Yes, it should. Those are all Git commands.

Comment: @TTT I think fredrik was thinking about some shell that could interpret @{u} before git can receive it as command line argument.

Comment: @LaurentG If true that would be pretty scary though, since `@,{,}` are all common characters in Git commands. Anyway, the syntax works in both Git Bash and Windows Command Line, at least.

Comment: @fredrik I added a link to the upstream shorthand documentation. (It's the red note slightly after the linked section.)